# Dynamic Dns changing for GCP f1 micro instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dynamic-dns, ghost-blog

I am quite new to this ordeal. I am trying to host my ghost blog on GCP f1 instance, the point being that I want to host a website free forever (as per the current condition). GCP f1 instance was the perfect choice for me, but I came to understand that google is making the reservation of static IP addresses not free. I had used a service called dynamic DNS previously and I was wondering if it would be possible to have such kind of a service on GCP, which informs cloudflare of the changed ephemeral IP on the instance to generate a new A record for the domain I am hosting.

Comment: The persistent IP address is only billed when the attached instance is not running, or it is not attached to any instance.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael mentioned in his comment is correct, you only need to pay for unattached reserved IP's. However, with regards to your concern, I've found this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#ipaddress) useful that describes about the pricing for the networking products.